# Elegant way to defining the various operations and costants

Tags: c++, class, enums, calculator, wxwidgets

I'm creating a C++ wxWidgets calculator application. I need a way of easily defining the various operations and costants that are usable in the program.
Right now, in my main frame class, I have these arrays declared privately:

```
const wxString ops[5] = //operations that require a number before and after
{
    L"+", 
    L"-", 
    L"\u00D7", //multiplication
    L"\u00F7", //division
    L"^"
};  
const wxString extra[10] = //operations that only require a number after (don't know the right name for this)
{
    L"\u221A", //square root
    L"sin", 
    L"cos", 
    L"tan", 
    L"arcsin", 
    L"arccos", 
    L"arctan"
};  
const wxString consts[2] = //constants
{
    L"\u03C0" //pi
};
```

I'm using wxString because in the function that parses the equation it checks if it finds one of these, gets the correspondent array index and uses it in a switch do to the actual calculation.

For example, if I type `sin45+5`, the parses finds `sin`, checks if it belongs to the `ops`, `extra` or `consts` array and then cycles through the `extra` array and gets that its index is 1 because it's the second element in the array. Then I have this code, which returns the result of the sin operation:

```
        switch (GetExtraId(op)) { default: return 0;
            case 0: return sqrt(b); //radice quadrata
            case 1: return sin(b * 3.14159265359 / 180); //trasformazione da radianti a gradi
            case 2: return cos(b * 3.14159265359 / 180);
            case 3: return tan(b * 3.14159265359 / 180);
            case 4: return asin(b) * 180 / 3.14159265359; 
            case 5: return acos(b) * 180 / 3.14159265359;
            case 6: return atan(b) * 180 / 3.14159265359;
        }
```

I'm asking: is there a more elegant way of doing this? The fact that if I want to create a button for the + operation I have to set its label as `ops[0]` is kind of inconvenient. I tried something like:

```
enum class ops : wxString
{
    add = L"+",
    sub = L"-",
    mul = L"\u00D7",
    div = L"\u00F7",
    pow = L"^"
};
```

But then I'd have to convert those to `int` somehow to be able to use them in the switch. Also, I cannot use wxString in enums as it isn't an integral type.

Comment: You probably want those names: binary operators/unary operators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like a classic case of `map` use. You can look toward this:

```
std::map<std::string, std::function<double(double, double)> ops;
```

Then populate it:

```
double add(double, double);
ops.insert({"+", add}); // Maps "+" to the pointer to add()
ops.emplace("-", subtract); // Or even like so
```

So, then you can directly call on a return from the `map`:

```
ops["+"](3.14, 1.61); // Returns 4.75
```

This way you query functions directly, without need for string to integer mapping and then `switch` based on this integer.

As to use with the wxString, you may want to check on this [list of conversions](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_string.html#string_conv).

Comment: Or even `ops.emplace("+", add);`

Comment: If I try to write `std::map < wxString, function<long double(long double, long double)> > binary;` I get E0864 function is not a model .

Comment: @iKebab897 can you make use of [these](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_string.html#string_conv) conversions and map some convertible type into the `std::map`>

Comment: It needs to be a wxString because it supports Unicode characters. Anyways the problem seems to be the word "function", as [MSVS2019 underlines it in red.](https://pasteboard.co/K8fEyQe.png)

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function

Comment: @iKebab897 yeah, check the link above: [function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)

Comment: It works now. But I also need each operation to also have some kind of ID (like if it was an enum): right now, if I want to create a button for an operation, I need to rewrite its symbol and set the button's label to it. I thought of using namespaces. Example: `namespace binary { wxString add(L"+"); }` then I insert the addition in a map which is also called `binary` like this: `binary.emplace(binary::add, [](long double a, long double b) { return a + b; });` Like this, I can set the button's label to `binary::add` and not to `L"+"`. What is the best approach for this?

Comment: Also, did I write the lambda function correctly in my previous comment?

Comment: @iKebab897 maybe then map it like so `map<pair<string, id_type>, function<int(int,int)>>`. The `namespace` also seems valid, it all depends on other design factors.

Comment: Should I create an enum for id_type? Also, what should I write to get che map's wxString from the id?